# Having trouble previewing reports

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I've created a new "Report Server Project" in VS2013 .Net 4.5. I've added a data source and the test connection succeeds. I've added a DataSet using the "Use a dataset embedded in my report" option choosing the data source previously created. The query type is Stored Procedure with a single text parameter. In the report data box I can right click my DataSet, choose Query, and execute the sproc. I see a grid populated correctly with my data.

However, when I try to create and preview a report it fails. I do the following:

Add a new report.
Drop a table on it from the toolbox.
Start dragging fields from my DataSet onto the table.
When I hit preview I see the following

[image]

Comment: I tried the following example and did not seem to have the "time" problem. http://www.rajbandi.net/replacing-report-viewer-date-parameter-default-date-picker-with-jquery-ui-date-picker/

Comment: What version of IE are you using? I have IE 11 and Chrome 39 and they seem to work as long as the date has a 12:00 time on the end. In IE can you hit F12 and then under emulation try to use a different "User agent string" and see which IE versions are not working for you? Normally I have reverse problem where IE works but Chrome does not. I had to do this in the past to get Chrome to work http://www.rajbandi.net/fixing-ssrs-report-viewer-control-date-picker-in-google-chrome/#comment-1484

Comment: A work around that you could do is set the ReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = False and then use your custom datepicker to set the report parameter like - ReportViewer..SetParameters("yourParameter") this way your web page is the one controlling the parameters and not the built in SSRS "ugly" parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66531/discussion-between-goroth-and-jt2ouan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "HACK" but it will do what you are asking.

```html
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication24._Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(pageLoadingHandler);

            function pageLoadingHandler() {
                fixParameters();
            }

            function fixParameters() {
                $("table[id^='ParametersGridReportViewer1']").find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
                    if (isDate($(this).attr("value"))) {
                        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 10));
                    }
                });
            }

            function isDate(date) {
                return ((new Date(date) !== "Invalid Date" && !isNaN(new Date(date))));
            }

        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="1184px" ShowParameterPrompts="True">
                <ServerReport ReportPath="/Report Project1/Report1" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Replace the "ReportViewer1" with the name of your report viewer.
This basically will check all input fields inside the report parameter table and if any of them look like dates then it will remove the time while loading.

**EDIT**
Added entire page code.

Comment: added the entire page code. There is no code behind.

Comment: Have you tried to move the code from the fixParameters into the pageloadinghandler and then delete the fixParameters function?

Comment: I thought you didn't want the timestamp?

Comment: I'm out of options. The code I listed above is pretty straight forward in that all it does is drop the time from the input box as it is being generated on "page load". It should not change when editing other parameters unless your report has cascading parameters. You can use the beginRequest on the PageRequestManager to add back the "12:00" before the value is being sent back to the server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311028%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66694/discussion-between-goroth-and-jt2ouan).